# Understanding Haskell types

Tags: haskell

I need to understand how types works and can be interpreted.

For example, if we take map function we have **map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]**

Well, how do I interpret this?

Comment: This is a pretty fundamental question about Haskell. What learning materials are you using? For example, http://learnyouahaskell.com/types-and-typeclasses has an extensive explanation of Haskell type notation.

Comment: Why are you asking such a basic question? Every Haskell tutorial very quickly gets to the answer of what you're asking. I get the feeling this is a homework assignment question (but I might be wrong).

Comment: Please read the Gentle Introduction to Haskell.

Answer (score 4):

`->` is a type constructor for the type of functions. It's a right-associative infix operator, meaning it's grouped together from the right. This means that we can rewrite the type by adding explicit grouping for the functions to the right side.

```
map :: (a -> b) ->  [a] -> [b]
map :: (a -> b) -> ([a] -> [b])
```

An infix expression for an operator `*` applied to two arguments, `x` and `y`, `x * y` can be written in prefix notation as `(*) a b`. We can rewrite the preceding type, starting with the outermost `->`, which is the one in the middle.

```
map :: (->) (a -> b) ([a] -> [b])
```

And we can now translate the last type into English

```
map ::   (->)                   (a -> b)                 ([a] -> [b])
map is a function that takes a "(a -> b)" and returns a "([a] -> [b])"
```

Where we interpret `a -> b ~ (->) a b` (here `~` means the types are equivalent) as

```
(->)                    a                b
function that takes an "a" and return a "b"
```

And interpret `[a] -> [b] ~ (->) [a] [b]` as

```
(->)                  [        a ]               [        b ]
function that takes a list of "a"s and returns a list of "b"s
```

We say "a function from `a` to `b`" as shorthand for "a function that takes an `a` and returns a `b`"

The `a`s and `b`s in the type signature are type variables, they can take on any type, which we call polymorphism. Occasionally, you will see this written explicitly in Haskell as `forall` So, in all we could say:

`map` is a polymorphic value for all types `a` and `b` which is a function that:

- takes a function from `a` to `b` and
- returns a function from a lists of `a`s to a list of `b`s.

Answer (score 3):

The fact that this signature contains `->` tells us it's a function. Whatever comes after the last `->` is the return type of the function once fully applied. Let's look at the individual pieces.

```
(a -> b)
```

This is the first argument, and it, too is a function. This means that `map` is a higher-order-function -- it takes a function as one of its arguments. `a -> b` itself is a function that transforms some value of type `a` into some value of type `b`.

```
[a]
```

The second argument. The square brackets is special syntax that denotes list. This argument, therefore, is a list with elements of type `a`.

```
[b]
```

The type of the result. Again, a list, but this time with elements of type `b`.

We can try to reason about this now. Given a function `a -> b` and a list of `a`, `map` seems to be (it really is) a function that transforms that list of `a`s into a list of `b`s.

Here's an example: `map (*2) [1,2,3]`. In this case, `a` is `Integer` (or some other integer type) and each element is doubled. `b`, too, is `Integer`, because `(*2)` assumes the same return type, so in the case the type variables `a` and `b` are the same. This need not be the case; we could have a different function instead of `(*2)`, say `show` which would have produced a `b` distinct from `a`, namely `String`.

Try them out in ghci. You can type in `map show [1,2,3]` directly and see the result. You can query the type of the expression by prepending :t to that line.

To learn more, you should look up one of the marvelous starter resources. [LYAH](http://learnyouahaskell.com/types-and-typeclasses) has an entire chapter dedicated to the basic understanding of types, and is definitely worth a read!